# Cross thread operation error showing a form during a form.show

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a tricky problem here that I have not been able to solve and neither have the people I asked on msdn forums.

I am using a third part product (signal lab from mitov.com) which is a set of .net components.
I have created a windows form app that works fine if it is run.
I now want to show this form from another form when this other form loads (or shows, or activates...).

I already have examples of this working with another form:  Here is the typical code:
I am loading a form (SecondForm) from the main program...

```
private void SecondForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Form _macros = new Macros(this);  //this works perfectly fine
     _macros.show(this);

     //this is where I have no success
     Form _spectrum = new SpectrumScope;
     _spectrum.Show();

}
```

I get various errors from no form displayed and then an exception about not instantiating the _spectrum, to an error about cross threaded operation not being allowed, to a blue screen with a message about clocks not being synchronized between processors.

If I place a button on "Second Form" and add the show form code to the click event, it works fine.
If I try to use form.activated, or form shown  instead of form.load there is not difference.
If I add a time to form Shown, which then does a button.performClick, there is no difference.

Obviously the form which contains many components (and many threads behind the scene) does not like the fact that it is not being opened by the user.

I'm fairly new to C# and I'm pretty sure this is threading related.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is the code example your real code? I wouldn't expect `new SpectrumScope;` (missing parentheses) to compile, and certainly I don't expect it to construct an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the blow code in your form load method, that should let .Net manage the threading for you.

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => (new SpectrumScope).Show()));
```

Comment: No, there is no change with this.  The code in the constructor of spectrumscope runs but then the debugger tells me that spectrumscope is not instantiated.

Comment: Hmm... maybe it doesn't like the `(new SpectrumScope)`. Create a SpectrumScope object in your SecondForm constructor and only calling Show on the SpectrumScope object in the form load.

Comment: Maybe this needs to be looked at differently...like I said I am fairly new. In my SecondForm class there are a number of static variables defined as and example  public static string volume;

Comment: Maybe this needs to be looked at differently.

Comment: What is the threading error that you are receiving? Do get the same error not running in debug mode?

Comment: Maybe this needs to be looked at differently. in the SecondForm there are a number of variables defined as public static string volume {get; set;}.  Now when the spectrumscope is loading, in it's constructor it tries to get the value of these and it seems that this is where the issue is.  I attempt to get the value as string myVolume = SecondForm.volume.  This is where it tells me I need to instantiate SecondForm.  Why is this?  It works if I load the spectrumscope via a button.  What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think that should be an issue because an instance of a class is not required for accessing static members and your `volume` variable is static

Comment: At this point, without seeing more of the code and knowing the exact error you are getting, it is hard to determine the issue.  I've testing the scenario you described with the static variables and I do not receive an error

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is fixed.  However, I don't really know why the issue exists.
In the spectrum form I reference static variables in the secondform.  Now, I use them as follows:

string newFrequency = secondForm.frequency;

This works.  However, some of these variables need to have this done:

string newBandWidth = secondForm.bandwidth.substring(2,4);

This is the command that fails.  I am told I need the "new" keywork.

I changed my code provide the the string without the need to get the substring and now it all works ok.
Anybody have any ideas?